# How can I select an element by class and text with XPath?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, automated-tests

I want to get the `a` element with xpath by the class `dropdown-item` and the inner text `lalalaaaaaaaaa`:

```
<a _ngcontent-pde-c12="" class="dropdown-item" style="padding:10px">
  <i _ngcontent-pde-c12="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-file-excel" style="color:#207144;font- 
  size:18px;"></i>
&nbsp;&nbsp;lalalaaaaaaaaa
</a>
```

but there is a problem with the part of the inner text - probably because of the `&nbsp;&nbsp;`.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `Xpath` with help of partial `text` and `class`

```
//a[@class='dropdown-item' and contains(., 'lalalaaaaaaaaa')]
```

only with `partial text`

```
//a[contains(., 'lalalaaaaaaaaa')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use contains in your XPath

```
xpath = "//a[@class='dropdown-item' and contains(@text, 'lalalaaaaaaaaa')]"
```